# ruby on rails - send email in definite time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to realize next thing in my app: user want's that every day or every tuesday at 15:00 he get email from my app, and email sending time is controlled by the user. How can I do it in my app?

Thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq). With delayed_job you can enqueue jobs to run in the future, so you could update the `run_at` to what the user specifies.

You will probably need to consider the timezone of the user, the delayed_job run_at will be UTC - *I wrote a blog post on [rails timezones](http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/) if you are interested*

Enqueue job with delayed job:

```
run_at = 'TODO: convert user specified params to UTC datetime'
job = SomeEmailJob.new(current_user.id)
Delayed::Job.enqueue(job, run_at: run_at)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a cron job where you specify a certain time to excute a certain action. For this you can use "Whenever" gem which is great with recurring tasks. With this gem you can write something like this

```
every :day, :at => '12:20am' do
  rake 'foo:bar'
end
```

For more details, check this out:

https://github.com/javan/whenever